# Pycharm out of memory error

Tags: python, pycharm, heap-memory

I have recently started to use pycharm but when I am running my code, it gives me out of memory error. I searched for increasing heap size in pycharm so i get recommendations to install Ant Window Tool from which I can increase the heap size. But when I searched in plugins there was no ant window available and i also do not know the root url from which I can download and install the plugin.

Anyone please suggest an alternative way of increasing the heap size. Thanks

Comment: did you try contacting pycharm customer support? Stackoverflow is for programming questions, not product support.

Answer (score 0):

Tip of the Day: NEVER mess around with the computer's heap. That will cause loads of other problems.

The out of memory error you are receiving could be one of two things:

**Option 1** - If you are getting a message from your operating system, your computer is actually out of memory (RAM). And trying to increase the amount allocated to the program will not do anything cause there is no more RAM.

**Option 2** - If this is an error in the compiler or debug window, than you appear to have an infinite loop in your code, causing the program to run out of memory. An uncaught infinite execution can cause the program to crash due to *out of memory*. Check your code over, it is most likely a logical error (which is why PyCharm would not have flagged it).